# What's the meaning of this @-sign in an Outlook message entry?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

My Outlook inbox message list contains an e-mail entry that displays a mysterious at-sign (@-sign). I don't think I've seen it before and so far haven't been able to find what it means. I've added a (partly redacted) screenshot. Does anybody know?

**Update 1:** the message doesn't use the mention/tagging feature. So nobody is @-mentioned in the e-mail. It contains only a short plain text message. I also sent a new message and @-mentioned someone in the body. But that message does **not** display the @-sign. So it doesn't seem to be related to this feature.

**Update 2 (the answer):** Some further testing showed it is indeed related to the mention feature. Technically, the @-sign will be displayed when the message has an `X-Mentions` header that contains your own e-mail address. The weird thing is that my message's body doesn't contain any mention. Further testing showed it's possible to @-mention someone in the Subject-field and then delete it. The message will still retain the `X-Mentions` header, but no longer contain the mention in the Subject or body. I think this is an Outlook bug. When deleting @-mentions from the message, the corresponding `X-Mentions` header items should also be deleted. This doesn't seem to happen for the Subject field.

I'm using Outlook 365 MSO (Version 2211 Build 16.0.15831.20220) 64 bits.

[image: Outlook message list with mysterious at-sign]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that someone mentioned you in the email:

```
Hello,

@someone, can you please take care?
```

[image: Microsoft: Use @mentions to get someone's attention]

[Microsoft: Use @mentions to get someone's attention](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mentions-to-get-someone-s-attention-90701709-5dc1-41c7-aa48-b01d4a46e8c7)

Comment: That's why I initially thought too. But the e-mail only contains plain text. It doesn't use the mention/tagging feature. I also tested this by sending a new e-mail and mentioning someone. But that e-mail doesn't display the @-sign.

Comment: @LeonZandman I just tried this with myself, e-mailing myself with an @ mention, but with the message format as plain text. The e-mail list shows the @, but the e-mail body has had the formatting stripped. So I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: Some further testing showed it is indeed related to the mention feature. Technically, the @-sign will be displayed when the message has an `X-Mentions` header that contains your own e-mail address. The weird thing is that my message body doesn't contain a mention. Further testing showed it's possible to @-mention someone in the Subject-field and then delete it. The message will retain the `X-Mentions` header, but no longer contain the mention in the Subject or body. I think this is an Outlook bug.